# how to take the derivative of an integral involving e and sec

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone help me with taking the derivative and second derivative with respect to $t$ of an integral like this

$\int_0^t \frac{1}{2} e^{-s} \sec s ds$  ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the derivative of $$\int_0^t \frac 12e^{-s} \sec s \, ds $$ with respect to $t$ is $$\frac 12e^{-t} \sec t $$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. and $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 12e^{-t} \sec t\right) = \frac 12\left(e^{-t} \sec t \tan t - \sec t e^{-t}\right)  = \frac 1 2e^{-t} \sec t \left( \tan t - 1\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Using Leibniz's integration rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int\limits_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(s,t) \, ds
=
\int\limits_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(s,t) \, ds +
f(b(t),t) b'(t) - f(a(t),t) a'(t)
$$
accounting here only for the upper integration bound being dependent on $t$:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int\limits_0^t \frac{1}{2} e^{-s} \sec s \, ds
= 
\int\limits_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{1}{2} e^{-s} \sec s\right) \, ds
+ \frac{1}{2} e^{-t} \sec t
= 
\frac{1}{2} e^{-t} \sec t
$$
The second derivative is then
$$
\frac{1}{2} e^{-t}(-\sec t + \tan t \sec t) =
\frac{1}{2} e^{-t} \sec t (\tan t - 1)
$$